# How to verify what parameters are passed to a static method in java

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermock

As a part of my Junit tests, I want to verify if I am calling a static method of an external class with the right parameters.

eg:- Suppose I have the following as the class under tests.

```
class A {
    public static void someMethod(String param){
          some.thirdpartyClass.someStaticMethod(param);
    }      
}
```

Now I want to test as a part of the test for someMethod, that I called the someStaticMethod with the parameter *param*

Whats the easiest way to do this? I tried going through power mock but couldn't find a way.

Comment: I'm not sure you _can_ do this.  Perhaps there's a more testable way to design this in the first place?

Comment: No..the restriction is because of the framework I am using.To be specific I am using the Playframework and trying to test the controllers by not verifying the result of the view, but testing if the right view name is being used instead.

Comment: As you are using Play Framework, you might be interested by their feedback on unit tests as well.

Comment: @Brice I saw their recommended way of testing controllers, but they suggest that we start asserting on the HTML contents that are returned from the controller, which I feel isnt really unit testing. For unit testing all I care about is the name of the template being called

Comment: @Ankit Oh, they say that... Well, I feel almost the same way as you. However you might be interested by [FluentLenium](https://github.com/FluentLenium/FluentLenium) which could fill the gap between what they say and what you want, if the template returns an element with a specific id.

Answer (score 5):

the easiest way is to use **powermock**.

Take a look here http://code.google.com/p/powermock/source/browse/trunk/modules/module-test/easymock/junit4-test/src/test/java/samples/junit4/singleton/MockStaticTest.java

Comment: Source is not available now.

Answer (score 1):

It's not difficult with PowerMock, but here is an easier solution using JMockit:

```
public class ATest
{
    @Test
    public void testSomeMethodInIsolation(@Mocked ThirdPartyClass tpc)
    {
        final String param = "testing";

        new A().someMethod(param);

        new Verifications() {{ ThirdPartyClass.someStaticMethod(param); }};
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried using this, but its not working out of the box for me....
It gives me java.lang.Exception: Method test should have no parameters

Comment: Move jmockit.jar before junit.jar in the runtime classpath. Or use TestNG.